# Dynamic insertion of javascript into JSP using servlets

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I'm developing an app using JSP and Servlets and I want to include a feature that when the user is creating a specific object (let's say client), he can insert JS code to execute when he sees the information for it. For example a graph, or load an image or something else specific for that client and while looking at other clients, the behavior of the page could be different.

What would be the best way to save and insert into the JSP that JS code to be executed? These are the options I've thought of:

1. Insert the JS code directly into the database as a string with the rest of the object's information, and then put it into a script tag in the JSP.
2. Let the user insert the URL for the script and save that address in the database and then in the JSP put that the script will be served from that URL.

But if there are other options that I'm not considering, I'm eager to know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not inserting that script in a file with .js as extension and save it's URL in DB

Comment: I think that's better, thanks, @PacMan

Comment: if there is any doubt with you can post your code and i can help i've implement the same procedure before